# Create entity classes from database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there any way in PHP to create models/entity classes directly from the database, maintaining the relationships between the tables/entities?

Comment: Maybe you could use some ORM library like [RedBeanPHP](http://redbeanphp.com/index.php) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package for auto-generating models from DB schema: https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator#help--options

Comment: Okay. Does this provides any relationships like hasOne or hasMany or belongsTo  ?

Comment: Nope, dont think there's a package available that can also autogenerate relationship functions

Comment: Doctrine can generarate also relationship functions